# Does it exist a function for which the derivative changes sign more than countably many times?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does there exist any function $f \in C^2[0,1]$; $f: [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$, for which the derivative changes sign more than countably many times?

Comment: No. Since $f\in\mathcal C^2[0,1]$, $f^\prime$ is continuous, so $\left\{\,x\,\big|\,f^\prime(x)>0\,\right\}$ is an open set and is the union of countable open intervals.

Comment: @FrankScience Why hide that perfectly good answer as a comment?

Comment: I agree with @mrf, make it an answer Frank.

Comment: @mrf I doubt it's a typo. We can consider a stronger one, say, if $f$ is only differentiable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @FrankScience, I don't understand the "typo" comment. Was that really meant for me?

Comment: Why do people keep directing their comments to me?

Comment: @mrf All you need is $f\in C^1$. So the $2$ could have been a type replacing a $1$. But as FrankScience indicates in his last comment, a revised question might be to just use differentiable with no assumption that even the first derivative is continuous. As for why you, you asked if a previous comment was really meant for you.

Comment: @BarbaraOsofsky I haven't said anything at all about the formulation of the question *or* the assumptions in Frank's solution. Your comment in particular is totally unrelated to my activity in this thread.

Comment: @mrf I'm sorry you think this is not related to this thread, but when Frank Science said to you "I doubt it's a typo. You replied to him 'I don't understand the "typo" comment.  Was that really meant for me?' He did not respond so I jumped in and said "All you need is $f\in C^1$. So the $2$ could have been a typ[o] replacing a $1$." Someone voted for that message from you to him quoted here.  I really had no intention of offending you, but that was the only way I could make sense of Frank's message to you, and thought it might be helpful to you to point it out.

Comment: @mrf As Barbara said, all we need is $f\in\mathcal C^1$, and according to my hint, it's unrelated to the fact that $f^\prime$ is a derivative (which only depends on the fact that it's continuous), so I think the answer is imperfect, and unless I get an idea to solve in the general case, I won't post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function $f'$ whose zero set is the Cantor set.  And on complementary intervals with length $3^{-k}$, $k$ odd, the function is positive, while on complementary intervals with $3^{-k}$, $k$ even, the function is negative.  Then could we say $f'$ "changes sign" at each point of the Cantor set (since there are positive values and negative values clustering at that point)?

[image: picture]

Comment: Would this be differentiable?

Comment: @Peter: Almost everywhere!

Comment: @AsafKaragila ¡=)! But don't we want it to be everywhere differentiable?

Comment: Each little bump is a $C^\infty$ bump...

Comment: @Peter: We? I don't mind a negligible set of mistakes... :-)

Comment: @Peter: Thanks.